# Uso dell'espressione "ce l'ha"

Tags: word-usage, regional

Ho passato qualche giorno a Firenze e là ho sentito usare l'espressione "ce l'ha" in frasi come:

> **Ce l'ha** qualcos'altro dopo? (Domanda fatta da una cameriera a mio marito, che aveva già finito il primo piatto, in una trattoria). 
>   **Ce l'ha** bisogno (Frase pronunciata da un cliente, che aveva ordinato per lui solo una bottiglia d'acqua naturale e un'altra d'acqua frizzante in una trattoria, dopo che la cameriera l'aveva avvertito che le bottiglie erano grandi. Il cliente era solo, ma aveva un cane.)

La mia domanda è sull'uso che se ne fa di questa espressione. Immagino si adoperi nel parlato informale. È così? Il suo uso è frequente in tutta Italia o soltanto in alcune regioni?

Comment: Potresti aggiungere le frasi subito precedenti e seguenti, o specificare il contesto? La forma "ci" + pronome diretto + verbo avere è normale nello scritto e nel parlato per dire il possesso di qualcosa (es. Hai una macchina? Sì, ce l'ho).

Comment: Grazie! Mi suonano davvero strane. La prima avrebbe senso se l'avesse detta tuo marito, la seconda mi suonerebbe se il cliente avesse detto qualcosa tipo "C'ho bisogno (di bere acqua)". Forse qualche toscano può aiutarci... [un piccolo suggerimento di sintassi: "dopo che la cameriera l'avvertisse" -> "dopo che la cameriera l'aveva avvertito"]

Comment: Anche per me la prima frase è strana è basta: non mi suona nemmeno dialettale e tanto meno toscana. Non può essere che la cameriera fosse straniera? Quanto alla seconda, non è possibile che tu abbia sentito male e sia «Ce ne ho [o “ce n'ho”] bisogno»?

Comment: Grazie mille, @Benedetta, ho fatto la correzione.

Comment: @DaG: Non mi è sembrata una cameriera straniera, ma non posso assicurare che fosse toscana.

Comment: @DaG: Quanto alla seconda frase, penso di aver sentito "ha" e non "ho", ma neanche in questo caso poso assicurare che il cliente fosse toscano. C'è tantissima gente questi giorni a Firenze...

Comment: Ho capito... Per il niente che può servire, aggiungo un'osservazione completamente empirica: ho sentito vari stranieri che parlano un buon italiano – magari imparato sul posto più che sulle grammatiche – usare in modo peculiare l'espressione “ce l'ho”. Dove per un italiano è una sorta di rafforzamento di “lo/la/li/le ho” (“Ce l'hai una penna?” “Sì, ce l'ho”), da stranieri l'ho spesso sentito usare anche senza un referente (“Io ce l'ho tre figli”). [segue]

Comment: Non so se nel caso della cameriera possa essere qualcosa del genere: in italiano standard si potrebbe chiedere “Ha qualcos'altro dopo?” (nel senso per lo più di “Ha già ordinato qualcos'altro?”), ma magari lei esprimeva in modo diverso.

Comment: Secondo me la prima frase potrebbe avere il senso di *Ha preso qualcos'altro dopo?*, la cameriera, se non sapeva cosa aveva ordinato tuo marito, avrebbe potuto chiederglielo (poteva essere anche *C'ha qualcos'altro dopo?*). La seconda così come l'hai riportata non ha senso, a meno che il cliente non indicasse la moglie intendendo che l'acqua l'aveva bisogno lei. Se l'acqua l'aveva bisogno lui avrebbe dovuto dire *Ce l'ho bisogno". Comunque non sono frasi da Accademia della Crusca.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Il cliente era solo.

Comment: Scusa, @CarLaTeX: Dove si dice “Ce l'ho bisogno” anziché “Ce ne ho bisogno”?

Comment: @DaG In milanese si dice

Comment: @Charo allora mi sa che aveva detto *Ce l'ho bisogno* o qualcos'altro... comunque non ti preoccupare, mi sembrano molto "slang" come frasi!

Comment: Ah, grazie, @CarLaTeX, non lo sapevo. A Milano si usa cioè “avere bisogno” come se fosse un verbo transitivo? Anche “avere voglia” e altre costruzioni simili?

Comment: @DaG Io sono milanese (anche se di milanesi a Milano ce ne sono pochi ahahah) e *ce l'ho bisogno* o *ce l'ho di bisogno* non mi suonano del tutto strane come espressioni. Non so se si usino anche in altre parti d'Italia... magari in tutto il Nord, anche in Toscana.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Adesso ricordo che il cliente era solo ma aveva un cane. Forse si riferiva al cane? (veramente non so cosa fece con le bottiglie di acqua).

Comment: @Charo Se si riferiva al cane per me avrebbe senso... Intendeva dire che il cane aveva bisogno dell'acqua...

Comment: @DaG Per le costruzioni simili direi di no: *Ce l'ho voglia* non l'ho mai sentito, né a Milano né altrove :)

Comment: @DaG Guarda qui e cerca *ce l'ho bisogno* http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ho-bisogno-di.746780/?hl=it la risposta dice *Orribile (per le mie orecchie) utilizzo lombardo, forse più dell'area milanese....* quindi direi che il cliente che ha sentito Charo era decisamente milanese ahahah

Comment: La prima frase potrebbe anche essere *\*c'ha qualcos'altro dopo?* -- forma sgrammaticata, ma comune nel parlato.

Comment: Non lo so, @Charo, ma forse `Ce l'ha ... dopo` può significare `Ce l'avrà ...` e quello lo stesso che `will you be having ...` in inglese?

Comment: Ritengo che i due esempi riportati siano semplicemente esempi di forme intensive.

Answer (score 1):

Come dici tu "**ce l'ha**" è una forma usata in un contesto piuttosto informale, anche se usando il condizionale (**ce l'avrebbe**), il termine assume una connotazione più di cortesia e di formalità.
Detto questo la prima frase (**ce l'ha** qualcos'altro dopo?) sarebbe corretta se fosse stato tuo marito a dirla alla cameriera. 
"**Ce l'ha**" è usato per chiedere qualcosa per ottenerlo: si può anche dire "**ha** qualcos'altro?" oppure "**avrebbe** qualcos'altro?"
La seconda frase mi sembra scorretta dal punto di vista grammaticale (la frase non sta in piedi)... piuttosto penso che il signore abbia detto "**Ce n'è** bisogno" oppure "**ne ha** bisogno (riferendosi al cane)", per indicare una necessità.
Detto questo, personalmente, ho riscontrato l'utilizzo di questi termini in maniera molto diffusa, indipendentemente dalla regione.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian Language Stack Exchange! Hai letto i commenti alla domanda? Avevamo già discusso, anche se, effettivamente, poi nessuno ha riassunto in una risposta...

Comment: Infatti ho risposto perché appunto vedevo una conclusione nei commenti ma nessuno che desse una risposta vera e propria... grazie :)